# When activiti calls an activity (external sub-process), the input parameters cannot be obtained in the sub-process

Tags: activiti, bpmn

**Main process bpmn:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
  <process id="MProcess_1" name="主流程" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="MStartEvent_1" name="主流程开启" activiti:initiator="admin">
      <outgoing>Flow_125mzno</outgoing>
    </startEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="Flow_125mzno" sourceRef="MStartEvent_1" targetRef="MActivity_088ikf9" />
    <callActivity
        id="MActivity_088ikf9"
        name="主流程调用子流程"
        calledElement="subProcess_1"
        activiti:businessKey="${businessKey}">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:in source="userList" target="userList" />
      </extensionElements>
      <incoming>Flow_125mzno</incoming>
      <outgoing>Flow_0o5vgkj</outgoing>
      <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics activiti:collection="userList">
        <completionCondition xsi:type="tFormalExpression">${activityTaskHandle.complete(execution)}</completionCondition>
      </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
    </callActivity>
    <endEvent id="MEvent_1ya9u23" name="主流程结束">
      <incoming>Flow_0o5vgkj</incoming>
    </endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="Flow_0o5vgkj" sourceRef="MActivity_088ikf9" targetRef="MEvent_1ya9u23" />
  </process>
</definitions>
```

**Subprocess bpmn:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
  <process id="subProcess_1" name="子流程" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="subStartEvent_1" name="子流程开启" activiti:initiator="admin">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener class="com.anke.module.activiti.listener.PlanTaskListener" event="start" />
      </extensionElements>
      <outgoing>subFlow_1tdgwu1</outgoing>
    </startEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="subFlow_1tdgwu1" sourceRef="subStartEvent_1" targetRef="subActivity_1b5vor5" />
    <userTask id="subActivity_1b5vor5" name="人工任务"  activiti:assignee="${userList}">
      <incoming>subFlow_1tdgwu1</incoming>
      <outgoing>Flow_18u8rta</outgoing>
    </userTask>
    <userTask id="subActivity_0l09p3p" name="管理审核" activiti:candidateGroups="otherTeam">
      <incoming>Flow_18u8rta</incoming>
      <outgoing>Flow_0cegds0</outgoing>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="Flow_18u8rta" sourceRef="subActivity_1b5vor5" targetRef="subActivity_0l09p3p" />
    <endEvent id="subEvent_1tkpbkh" name="子流程结束">
      <incoming>Flow_0cegds0</incoming>
    </endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="Flow_0cegds0" sourceRef="subActivity_0l09p3p" targetRef="subEvent_1tkpbkh" />
  </process>
</definitions>
```

**startup error:**

```
2022-01-26 16:13:12.682 ERROR 2384 --- [    Test worker] o.a.e.impl.interceptor.CommandContext    : masked exception in command context. for root cause, see below as it will be rethrown later.

org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${userList}
```

**java code:**

```
securityUtil.logInAs("admin");
Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
List<String> userList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("zxy", "stdio", "admin"));
variables.put("userList", userList);
variables.put("businessKey", "1122334455");
ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("MProcess_1", "12345", variables);
```

Do the "activiti:in" input parameters need to be declared in the subprocess bpmn template? Or what label is required to undertake to use? Or is there a problem with my template?

At the same time, the variables set by "activiti:elementVariable='user'" cannot be passed to the sub-process and used by "${user}"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is that userList hasn't been passed into the sub process, I think the issue is that userList is a hashmap and the activiti:assignee requires a single user as a string.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case. I created a process variable "username" of type string when the main process started, passed it to the subprocess via "<activiti:in source="username" target="username" />", and then passed it in the subprocess via "$ {username}" got it, but still got an error: "Unknown property used in expression: ${username}". Do you know why? thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using Activiti 6.x, try putting a breakpoint in https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/6.x/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/bpmn/behavior/CallActivityBehavior.java (search for  "copy process variables". You can at least see if the variable is being set.

Comment: I found the problem, but I don't know why.In the hasExtensionsFor method of the ProcessExtensionService class:`public boolean hasExtensionsFor(String processDefinitionKey) {
        return processExtensionModelMap.containsKey(processDefinitionKey);
    }`.When the program runs here, it will check whether there is a sub-process key in processExtensionModelMap, but my processExtensionModelMap is empty, so I skip passing parameters for the sub-process.Do you know why? Thank you so much